# Split a String but remove delimeters only and keep spaces - java

Tags: java, arrays, string, split

I have a string like this:

```
String str = "SOFTDRINK,SD03,Lemon juice,lemon juice,lemonjuice.img,30000.0";

// How can i get this expected string array:
String[] expected = ["SOFTDRINK","SD03","Lemon juice","lemonjuice","lemonjuice.img","30000.0"];
```

I use .split(",") and iterate the array, it would be a errors at "Lemon juice" where there is a space.

UPDATE:
No error of .split(",") faced.
My String str wasn't returned as shown above so I faced errors related to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**i dont think you should face any error here**

***anyways try this , you will get your expected output***

```
    String str = "SOFTDRINK,SD03,Lemon juice,lemon juice,lemonjuice.img,30000.0";
    String[] expected = str.split(",");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(expected));
```

*even if it doesnt work out add more of your code*

Comment: It seems like I have problems with getting the String str at first in my code. Thanks.